# Can't convert HttpStringContent to HttpContent

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I try create Windows Store app. And i need send post request, but i have a problem. 
My method:

```
       private async Task<string> POST(byte[] pic, string upload_url)
    {


        var multipartContent = new System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent();
        multipartContent.Add(new System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent(pic), "photo");
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var response = await client.PostAsync(
new Uri(upload_url),
multipartContent);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Always i have Task member after return. With status-Waiting for activation. Where error? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I think you are mixing `System.Net.Http` and `Windows.Web.Http`. Try [StringContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: I tried. Recived same...              `var stringContent = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(String.Format("photo:{0}",pic));`